# Setting print size preset in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator, printing

I've been using Folder Actions to automate printing photos taken from OS X built-in Photo Booth software. The AppleScript I use is as follows:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    try
        tell application "Canon iP2700 series"
            activate
            print added_items
            quit
        end tell
    end try
end adding folder items to
```

Is there anyway I can set the print job to use a preset size using **AppleScript** or maybe **change the defaults** so that AppleScript prints uses that size by default?

I've noticed that they use the size at:

System Preferences > Printers & Scanners > Default paper size

But I require the printer to print at 75x105mm which is not in any preset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I say anything that you already know I apologize.

It all starts with your printer capability.

Does the Canon supports that size?

Open a app like TextEdit and use the "Page Setup".

Now select your printer and select the print size if available. If not available use the Manage Custom Size and add new size (+) and the dimensions.

Example:

[image]

Set it up:

[image]

Now go to Print (in TextEdit) and select the Printer & Scanner preferences and select default size.

[image]

size
[image]

Comment: Yes, I can print the custom size I want via print dialog just fine. I am attempting to do the same thing using only AppleScript.

Comment: Now when you use your AppleScript to print it will print in that selected size.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I missed out a portion of your answer. I'm gonna try it out. Thanks so much